# Symfony2.8 and Doctrine2 issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I must be missing something here. I removed a table from my DB and removed Entity file for that table from symfony project. Next I created table with the same name and had doctrine recreate the entity from that table. all went fine. Important to mention is that column names have change but the table name is the same.
When I go adjusted all the variable names in twig and controller and run the code I get this error: `Property AppBundle\Entity\WeatherSpecials::$df_per does not exist` but $df_per is no longer anywhere in the code, I removed it, it existed in the old entity but not in new one. how does this happen, how can symfony or doctrine remember old variable and reference it in the error. I feel like I'm really missing something here.

Comment: have you try clear cache by console symfony?

Comment: Have you restarted your PHP server to clear any OpCache?

Comment: That was the issue here, APC cache had to be clear due to UnitofWork in doctrine that cached that var.

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be it exists in the cache. Try clear the cache.

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=[ENV]
```

Comment: Did that few times, even deleted the entire /app/cache folder. `CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Property AppBundle\Entity\WeatherSpecials::$df_per does not exist" at /var/www/symfony/project2/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php line 80 `

Comment: @user1529918 Are you sure you are checking the right source? Like missing sync the dev code to the deployed machine.

Comment: I'm doing that on local box, no sync or anything in the way. Any good way to start troubleshooting this?

Comment: Show the result of `grep -rin df_per /var/www/symfony/project2`

Comment: `xfloyd@ubuntu14:/var/www/symfony/project2$ grep -rin df_per /var/www/symfony/project2
/var/www/symfony/project2/src/AppBundle/Entity/WeatherSpecials.php:27:     * @ORM\Column(name="df_per", type="boolean", nullable=true)
/var/www/symfony/project2/src/AppBundle/Entity/WeatherSpecials.php~:27:     * @ORM\Column(name="df_per", type="boolean", nullable=true)
`

Comment: It exist there, but I can rename it there and the error still says `df_per`

Comment: Did you do what @Aerendir suggested?  Verify that you don't have multiple mapping files lurking about?  It's quite common especially if xml/yaml files were originally generated under Resources/doctrine then the developer switches to annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I renamed the entity and now it works, but what the heck. Someone got to have some understanding how this thing "remember" it has to store it somewhere somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Doctrine didn't created the XML files to map your database structure. Maybe it did this and also if you delete the entity Doctrine continue to use the xml files instead of recreate them.

From the [Symfony's Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html):

> The first step towards building entity classes from an existing
>   database is to ask Doctrine to introspect the database and generate
>   the corresponding metadata files. Metadata files describe the entity
>   class to generate based on table fields.
>
> `$ php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml`
>
> This command line tool asks Doctrine to introspect the database and
>   generate the XML metadata files under the
>   src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine folder of your bundle.
>   This generates two files: BlogPost.orm.xml and BlogComment.orm.xml.